# Using parameters throughout multiple subroutines python

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to write a program where the user inputs what colour carpet they would like and then depending on what carpet and what area they have inputted it will give them a different price, However my current issue is using the parameters correctly since I am very new to both using python and to programming. The current program specification requires the use of subroutines. An example problem is with my last line main(exit1) where it says that exit1 isn't defined and if I try to edit the code to main() it says that exit1 is required. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
def prices():
    PriceA = 40
    PriceB = 50
    PriceC = 60
def main(exit1):
    exit1 = False
    while exit1 == False:
        carpet = str(input("What carpet would you like blue, red or yellow "))
        carpet = carpet.upper()
        if carpet == "X":
            exit1 = True
        else:
            width = int(input("What is the width of the room in M^2 "))
            height = int(input("What is the height of the room in M^2 "))
            area = width * height   


            if carpet == "BLUE":          
                a(area)

            elif carpet == "RED":
                b(area)

            elif carpet == "YELLOW":
                c(area)


            else:
                print("Invalid carpet")
                cost = 0
                output(cost)





def output(cost, exit1):
print ("the price is £", cost)


def a(area, PriceA):
    cost = PriceA * area
    output(cost)

def b(area, PriceB):
    cost = PriceB * area
    output(cost)

def c(area, PriceC):
    cost = PriceC * area
    output(cost)

main(exit1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass in a variable as an argument to the `main` function on the last line of your program, but you have not defined the `exit1` variable before that line is executed (you define it within the scope of the `main` function). To achieve what you want to do you don't need to provide `main` with the `exit1` argument, so you can just remove it from the function definition and the function call.

```
def main():
    ...

...

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that a variable needs to be defined before it can be entered into a function. I fixed the code and made a few corrections it also appeared that you had an indentation error and didn't feed in enough arguments into your functions when you called them. The code ive written is a bit easier to follwo. If I have done anything you dont understand send me a message, otherwise I recommend sites such as code acadamy and pythonprogramming .net.
    def main():

```
    PriceA = 40
    PriceB = 50
    PriceC = 60
    while True:
        carpet = str(input('What carpet would you like blue, red or yellow? '))
        carpet = carpet.upper()
        if carpet == 'X':
            break
        else:
            width = int(input("What is the width of the room in M? "))
            height = int(input("What is the height of the room in M? "))
            area = width * height

        if carpet == "BLUE":          
            output(area,PriceA)

        elif carpet == "RED":          
            output(area,PriceB)

        elif carpet == "YELLOW":          
            output(area,PriceC)
        else:
            print('Invalid carpet')
def output(area,Price):
    cost = area*Price
    print('the price is £',cost)
main()
```